# AMD GPU on Mac not showing up?

Tags: gpu, osx

I installed Blender 3.0 Cycles X using a.dmg file. I've tried 2.93 but that doesn't work either. The GPU is AMD Radeon R9 M370X, and I've checked Blender's website and it should work (OpenGL is 4.1) according to support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823, and the Mac is a Retina 5K, 27-inch, Mid 2015. What's happening and how do I fix it?
Here's a screenshot of what happens when I pull up the system preferences:
[image]

Comment: i guess they dropped support for opengl, it is written on website https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles

Answer (score 1):

Go to addon's and search for Cycles and see what comes up. The original cycles renderer is technically considered an addon - maybe you have to enable it:

[image: Cycles]